# Kubuntu 16.04.1 boots slowly

Tags: boot, 16.04, kubuntu

I have been using Kubuntu 16.04.1 for almost a month, so far so good, but the boot is very slow, I was using Ubuntu Gnome before it and it booted in 5 seconds, Kubuntu takes a minute and a half just loading the Kubuntu logo, And nothing else is installed alongside Kubuntu.

Any idea how to fix this? I have an SSD by the way.

Output of `systemd-analyze blame`:

```
       680ms dev-sda1.device
       670ms apt-daily.service
       491ms grub-common.service
       487ms accounts-daemon.service
       459ms NetworkManager.service
       154ms ondemand.service
       151ms systemd-udev-trigger.service
       140ms ModemManager.service
       138ms gpu-manager.service
       129ms upower.service
       126ms apparmor.service
       118ms networking.service
       109ms thermald.service
       108ms console-setup.service
       107ms systemd-logind.service
       103ms irqbalance.service
        83ms apport.service
        80ms keyboard-setup.service
        61ms udisks2.service
        53ms alsa-restore.service
        48ms rsyslog.service
        47ms pppd-dns.service
        41ms systemd-journald.service
        38ms snapd.autoimport.service
        35ms systemd-user-sessions.service
        34ms avahi-daemon.service
        34ms systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service
        34ms plymouth-start.service
        32ms systemd-rfkill.service
        31ms plymouth-quit.service
        31ms systemd-journal-flush.service
        28ms plymouth-read-write.service
        25ms user@1000.service
        24ms resolvconf.service
```

lines 1-34

systemd-analyze critical-chain output:

```
graphical.target @1min 30.518s └─multi-user.target @1min 30.493s   └─getty.target @1min 30.459s
    └─getty@tty1.service @1min 30.459s
      └─rc-local.service @1min 30.453s +1ms
        └─network.target @1min 30.433s
          └─wpa_supplicant.service @1min 30.625s +28ms
            └─basic.target @1min 30.197s
              └─sockets.target @1min 30.197s
                └─snapd.socket @1min 30.195s +1ms
                  └─sysinit.target @1min 30.194s
                    └─systemd-backlight@backlight:intel_backlight.service >@525ms +2ms
                      └─system-systemd\x2dbacklight.slice @511ms
                        └─system.slice @126ms    
                   └─-.slice @125ms
```

Comment: Add `systemd-analyze blame` to your question

Comment: As a tag? To the question!

Comment: No, please edit your question and add the results of the command mentioned in the above comment.

Comment: @CelticWarrior I added the output to the question.

Comment: Please add `systemd-analyze critical-chain` too

Comment: @M.Becerra I added it.

Comment: I added all the outputs, please look at them and tell me whats wrong with the boot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While all of your input was helpful (and I thank you for that), no one was actually able to "fix" the issue for me, the computer took 1 minute 48 seconds to boot and that's a lot even for windows installed on a 5400 rpm HDD!).

Now let's get to the juicy stuff:

At first I went to my BIOS and changed the Sata mode from AHCI to Compatible, Ubuntu gnome wouldn't load unless the controller was AHCI.

And disabled Intel Virtualization Technology because I no longer use VirtualBox.

Then I edited the /etc/fstab because I deleted the swap that came with Kubuntu and it was still mentioned there (totally forgot to mention it in the question, sorry! (The BLKID was matching and I matched it after deleting swap)

It was like this:

> ## /etc/fstab: static file system information.
>
> #
>
> ## Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
>
> ## device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
>
> ## that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
>
> #
>
> ## / was on /dev/sda1 during installation UUID=4840d72b-2435-4dc1-9227-ab7671fd3d93 /               ext4
>
> errors=remount-ro 0       1
>
> ## swap was on /dev/sda5 during installation UUID=0023c124-ea85-41d2-834c-83f6877d6959 none            swap    sw
>
> 0       0

And simply became this

> ## /etc/fstab: static file system information.
>
> #
>
> ## Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
>
> ## device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
>
> ## that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
>
> #
>
> ## / was on /dev/sda1 during installation UUID=4840d72b-2435-4dc1-9227-ab7671fd3d93 /               ext4
>
> errors=remount-ro 0       1

Then I went to /etc/systemd/system.conf and removed the comment from

> ## DefaultTimeoutStartSec=90s
>
> ## DefaultTimeoutStopSec=90s

via the command sudo kate /etc/systemd/system.conf

which was set to 90 seconds by default!! And set it to one second!

> DefaultTimeoutStartSec=1s
>   DefaultTimeoutStopSec=1s

Finally, I went to grub via sudo kate /etc/default/grub and added raid=noautodetect to GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT to become:

> GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash raid=noautodetect"

Then sudo update grub 2
sudo update grub

Boot time is now 19 seconds.

I've also updated the kernel to 4.10, which didn't affect the boot time but thought it would be helpful to mention.

Answer (score 2):

Well, *Kubuntu* is the slowest ubuntu-based distro.

If you want to make it faster, try to:

- install [e4rat](http://www.linuxlinks.com/article/20120218062227199/e4rat.html) (not recommended if you use an SSD);
- Disable useless services. I may suggest you to disable *network manager*, the *splash screen* ([How to disable Plymouth](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-mint-84/how-to-disable-plymouth-in-mint-ubuntu-827422/)), *wpa_supplicant*, your *display manager* (*KDM*) - just use *TTY*;
- Remove bloatware packages (packages you never use but are preinstalled)

... or just install Xubuntu / Lubuntu.

Comment: Thanks for the load of suggestions @Thomas William and I've disabled Plymouth already and removed a lot of useless bloatware packages, I'm yet to try e4rat but if it's bad for the SSD I'll skip it!

Answer (score 2):

You didn´t said where Kubuntu is installed - on your laptop, notebook... and nothing said about performance.

Anyway, try to change default boot time. To do this, open your terminal and run:

```
gksudo kate /etc/default/grub
```

You will see `GRUB_TIMEOUT=10` - by default is 10 second, but you can change it with 3 etc.

Then you need to apply changes using command `sudo update-grub`. After that reboot your system.

Also, if you´re not familiar with terminal or just want to do this easier, you can use [Grub Customizer](https://launchpad.net/grub-customizer)

Comment: Editing the settings to two seconds rather than one had no effect on the boot process because the delay is with the Kubuntu logo glowing, thanks for the try tho :)

Comment: @MuaadElSharif Obviously very good laptop performance. :)
You´re welcome. Really I have no idea why is that. Mystery for me, like about 7 months ago, when I installed Lubuntu (which is represents like lightweight os) on low-performance notebook, and it is been so slowly so I must install another one (as I can remember, I was choose Zorin OS, which is work very good).