# Is my SSD dying? Please help!

Tags: 16.04, kubuntu, ssd

At this point, I’m not sure if my SSD is dying, or if I have other issues.
At first I started getting the [ata COMRESET failed (error =-16)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/901069/kubuntu-16-04-2-freezes-error-message-is-ata1comreset-failed-errno-16) on boot, but the computer would boot and run fine, with the exception of it hanging every once in a while.

I thought the reason of the error was because of a checksum not matching due to a bad download (as it turns out Kubuntu uses SHA256 rather than MD5 for checksum) and downloaded  Kubuntu 16.04.2 again.

Before reinstalling I went and installed Windows (forgive me Stallman) and used it to update the firmware of the SSD -Since [the manufacturer](https://www.silicon-power.com/web/en_gb/product-2) didn’t and won’t provide an updater for Linux, and Windows didn’t report any issues with the drive as I checked it several times, and did so with the update tool (that is also a check tool), which says that the SSD is clean.

I didn’t want to update the bios as it might brick my computer if I do it wrong.

The disk is running fine and there is no data loss, and the only indicator of trouble is the message displayed sometimes when I boot, and when I booted from a live disk this is a part of what I got before booting into live mode.

```
[        7.332980] ata3: link is slow to respond, please be patient
(ready=0) [       11.877170] ata3: COMRESET failed (errno=-16). [     
  17.237292] ata3: link is slow to respond, please be patient (ready=0) [       21.934657] ata3: COMRESET failed
 (errno=-16). [     
 27.294779] ata3: link is slow to respond, please be patient (ready=0) Limiting link speed to 1.5 GB
```

I checked it using Parted Magic and this is the log I got, it passed all the tests and the S.M.A.R.T says it’s healthy (and so did the manufacturer tool).

```
smartctl 5.43 2012-06-30 r3573 [i686-linux-3.10.4-pmagic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-12 by Bruce Allen, http://smartmontools.sourceforge.net

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Device Model:     SPCC Solid State Disk
Serial Number:    F4C3075B14D000003262
Firmware Version: S9FM02.8
User Capacity:    120,034,123,776 bytes [120 GB]
Sector Size:      512 bytes logical/physical
Device is:        Not in smartctl database [for details use: -P showall]
ATA Version is:   8
ATA Standard is:  ACS-3 (revision not indicated)
Local Time is:    Fri Apr 21 10:43:21 2017 UTC
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x00) Offline data collection activity
                    was never started.
                    Auto Offline Data Collection: Disabled.
Self-test execution status:      (   0) The previous self-test routine completed
                    without error or no self-test has ever 
                    been run.
Total time to complete Offline 
data collection:        (   30) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:            (0x7b) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                    Auto Offline data collection on/off support.
                    Suspend Offline collection upon new
                    command.
                    Offline surface scan supported.
                    Self-test supported.
                    Conveyance Self-test supported.
                    Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                    power-saving mode.
                    Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                    General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine 
recommended polling time:    (   1) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:    (   2) minutes.
Conveyance self-test routine
recommended polling time:    (   2) minutes.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 16
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x000a   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0012   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       3341
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0012   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       1455
168 Unknown_Attribute       0x0012   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
170 Unknown_Attribute       0x0013   100   100   010    Pre-fail  Always       -       25
173 Unknown_Attribute       0x0000   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       50135087
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0012   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       51
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0023   070   070   000    Pre-fail  Always       -       30
196 Reallocated_Event_Count 0x0000   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
218 Unknown_Attribute       0x0000   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       8428
241 Total_LBAs_Written      0x0012   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       2691971

SMART Error Log Version: 1
ATA Error Count: 217 (device log contains only the most recent five errors)
    CR = Command Register [HEX]
    FR = Features Register [HEX]
    SC = Sector Count Register [HEX]
    SN = Sector Number Register [HEX]
    CL = Cylinder Low Register [HEX]
    CH = Cylinder High Register [HEX]
    DH = Device/Head Register [HEX]
    DC = Device Command Register [HEX]
    ER = Error register [HEX]
    ST = Status register [HEX]
Powered_Up_Time is measured from power on, and printed as
DDd+hh:mm:SS.sss where DD=days, hh=hours, mm=minutes,
SS=sec, and sss=millisec. It "wraps" after 49.710 days.

Error 217 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 0 hours (0 days + 0 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  84 51 00 10 47 68 e0  Error: ICRC, ABRT at LBA = 0x00684710 = 6833936

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  ca 00 00 10 47 68 e0 00      00:02:23.733  WRITE DMA
  ca 00 00 10 46 68 e0 00      00:02:23.732  WRITE DMA
  ca 00 00 10 45 68 e0 00      00:02:23.731  WRITE DMA
  ca 00 00 10 44 68 e0 00      00:02:23.730  WRITE DMA
  ca 00 00 10 43 68 e0 00      00:02:23.729  WRITE DMA

Error 216 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 0 hours (0 days + 0 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  84 51 00 10 23 68 e0  Error: ICRC, ABRT at LBA = 0x00682310 = 6824720

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  ca 00 00 10 23 68 e0 00      00:02:18.108  WRITE DMA
  ca 00 00 10 22 68 e0 00      00:02:18.108  WRITE DMA
  ca 00 00 10 21 68 e0 00      00:02:18.107  WRITE DMA
  ca 00 00 10 20 68 e0 00      00:02:18.106  WRITE DMA
  ca 00 00 10 1f 68 e0 00      00:02:18.105  WRITE DMA

Error 215 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 0 hours (0 days + 0 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  84 51 00 f8 15 68 e0  Error: ABRT at LBA = 0x006815f8 = 6821368

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  c5 00 00 f8 15 68 e0 00      00:02:13.687  WRITE MULTIPLE
  c5 00 00 f8 14 68 e0 00      00:02:13.661  WRITE MULTIPLE
  ca 00 18 f8 17 68 e0 00      00:02:13.661  WRITE DMA
  ca 00 00 f8 16 68 e0 00      00:02:13.660  WRITE DMA
  ca 00 00 f8 15 68 e0 00      00:02:13.656  WRITE DMA

Error 214 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 0 hours (0 days + 0 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  84 51 00 f8 14 68 e0  Error: ABRT at LBA = 0x006814f8 = 6821112

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  c5 00 00 f8 14 68 e0 00      00:02:13.661  WRITE MULTIPLE
  ca 00 18 f8 17 68 e0 00      00:02:13.661  WRITE DMA
  ca 00 00 f8 16 68 e0 00      00:02:13.660  WRITE DMA
  ca 00 00 f8 15 68 e0 00      00:02:13.656  WRITE DMA
  ca 00 00 f8 14 68 e0 00      00:02:13.651  WRITE DMA

Error 213 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 0 hours (0 days + 0 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  84 51 00 f8 15 68 e0  Error: ICRC, ABRT at LBA = 0x006815f8 = 6821368

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  ca 00 00 f8 15 68 e0 00      00:02:13.656  WRITE DMA
  ca 00 00 f8 14 68 e0 00      00:02:13.651  WRITE DMA
  c8 00 09 20 6a c8 e0 00      00:02:13.633  READ DMA
  c8 00 07 28 16 03 e1 00      00:02:13.630  READ DMA
  06 01 01 00 00 00 e0 00      00:02:13.614  [RESERVED]

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
# 1  Conveyance offline  Completed without error       00%      3341         -
# 2  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      3341         -
# 3  Extended offline    Completed without error       00%      3149         -
# 4  Conveyance offline  Completed without error       00%      3148         -
# 5  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      3148         -
# 6  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      2197         -
# 7  Conveyance offline  Completed without error       00%         0         -
# 8  Extended offline    Completed without error       00%         0         -
# 9  Short offline       Completed without error       00%         0         -

Note: selective self-test log revision number (0) not 1 implies that no selective self-test has ever been run
SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 0
Note: revision number not 1 implies that no selective self-test has ever been run
 SPAN  MIN_LBA  MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
    1        0        0  Not_testing
    2        0        0  Not_testing
    3        0        0  Not_testing
    4        0        0  Not_testing
    5        0        0  Not_testing
Selective self-test flags (0x0):
  After scanning selected spans, do NOT read-scan remainder of disk.
If Selective self-test is pending on power-up, resume after 0 minute delay.
```

When I used another disk and booted from live disk it didn’t display the messages.

Is [my SSD](https://www.silicon-power.com/web/en_gb/product-2) dying? I had it for almost a a year now. 
I’m too afraid of using my computer, and want to make sure that the disk is either OK and usable or dead and needs to be replaced.

In all cases I don't use this disk for data storage as it's a small drive (only 111 GB) and I only got it to make the computer boot faster and to run programs faster.

P.S: I don't have any customizations or special software installed.

P.S.S: Used to have the recovering journal issue, gone now.

Comment: All those **Unknown attributes** make things quite difficult.  If I were you, I would keep checking this line daily: **ATA Error Count: 217** to make sure 217 doesn't change.  If it does, I'm pretty sure there's an ongoing issue there.

Comment: Have you ever run fstrim manually on the drive?

Comment: @ubfan1 Not that I know of, no.

Comment: @heynnema is there an output to expect out of this command?

Comment: What is fstrim supposed to do @ubfan1

Comment: Okay I didn't try it and won't try it. What about the fstrim?

Comment: An `fstrim` discards blocks that are not used by the file system. It is okay and might even be done automatically, but as it also causes wear you shouldn't do it extremely often. There should be no harm in running it once or twice manually. Note that you need to specify the mountpoint (directory name like `/`) of the mounted file system as argument though, not the device. I am not sure whether it would affect the problem you describe though.

Comment: @ByteCommander good catch. I obviously wasn't thinking. I've deleted the comment, and OP didn't try it.

Comment: I'm still using it (and am now) but with a grain of salt, still a bit unsure of it.

Comment: So far it's working and the error count is at 217, didn't give the error code so far.

Comment: Have you tried using a different SATA cable? SATA cables are so cheap that it makes sense to swap one out whenever you think there may be an issue caused by it. Also, have you tried a different SATA port?

Comment: @i_pk_pjers_i It's a laptop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So far the disk seems to be working and the error count is at 217. Could it have been the corrupted ISO that I downloaded which started super slow and then I had to tweak it to run faster?

What I did is installing an SSD firmware update under windows (due to lack of software by manufacturer) and then installed a fresh install of Kubuntu 16.04.2

So I'm marking this as solved until further notice.

My question about slow boot and tweaks to fix:

[Kubuntu 16.04.1 boots slowly](https://askubuntu.com/questions/887423/kubuntu-16-04-1-boots-slowly)

My question about SSD errors and possible fixes:

[Kubuntu 16.04.2 freezes, error message is ata1:COMRESET failed (errno=-16)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/901069/kubuntu-16-04-2-freezes-error-message-is-ata1comreset-failed-errno-16)